# Sub Navigation Display Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I am building a website with some tabs at the top one of the tabs has sub navigation but I am having some trouble with the way it displays.

**ASPX Page**

```
<div id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="tab1">
                            <a href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab2">
                            <a href="AllHouses.aspx">Houses</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li> 
                                    <a href="Houses.aspx">Search Houses</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab3">
                            <a href="Events.aspx">Events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab4">
                            <a href="Maps.aspx">Maps</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab5">
                            <a href="About.aspx">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab6">
                            <a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="tab7">
                            <a href="Links.aspx">Links</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

My sub navigation is the search houses tab under the houses tab.

**CSS**

```
#navigation {
    background: url(../images/bg-navigation.png) no-repeat;
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    width: 860px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

    #navigation ul {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 860px;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #navigation li {
        float: left;
        background-position: 0 -118px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 49px;
        width: 122px;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 1px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #navigation li:first-child {
            background: none;
            margin-left: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        #navigation li a {
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            font: bold 14px/48px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            height: 49px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

            #navigation li a:hover {
                background-position: 0 -59px;
                color: #6d6157;
            }

        #navigation li.selected a {
            background-position: 0 0;
            color: #e4e1bd;
        }
```

**Function To Select Tab On Master Page**

```
 function setCurrentTab(selectedTab) {
            $('li').removeClass('selected');
            $('[id=' + selectedTab + ']').addClass('selected');
        }
```

**Houses Function**

```
$(function () { setCurrentTab('tab2'); });
```

**Search Houses Function**

```
$(function () { setCurrentTab('tab2'); });
```

Its 'tab2' also because I want the houses tab to stay selected not the search houses one.

**Preview**

[image]

This is the home page running the highlighted part is the sub navigation tab "search houses" which you should not be able to see until I hover over the houses tab.

[image]

I am hovering over the houses tab but the sub navigation is not being displayed but it is still there in the highlighted part.

[image]

When I move down to the highlighted part it displays the search houses tab now.

[image]

When I click houses tab both of the tab get selected which I don't want I only want the houses tab selected.

[image]

The same happens when I click search houses. I just want the houses selected.

- I don't want the sub navigation always displayed like in the first image.
- I only want it displayed when I hover over the houses tab like in the second image but display it like it is in the third image and not have to move down to the highlighted part/search houses tab to be able to see it.
- I want the houses tab to be selected only for the both houses and search houses page.

I'm pretty sure its a styling issue but I cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a shot, please see my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/9r6u3z74/).

I used background color in the fiddle since I don't have access to the image you used.

For the submenu, I added the style below so that the submenu is hidden until hovered:

```
#navigation li ul {
    display: none;
    background: #ddd;
}
#navigation li:hover ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 1px;
}
```

I also modified this part (required for the submenu positioning) where I added the `position: relative` style.

```
#navigation li {
    float: left;
    background-position: 0 -118px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 49px;
    width: 122px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```